# R tibble error when training

Tags: r, error-handling, r-caret, training-data, tibble

I'm training a model with Caret package. The training table if fine and I don't do any changes to it.

Why then am I getting the `Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.` error?

Comment: It's a warning, no?

Comment: It is, but, I am training a cart model and each time I get this warning, instead of a tree the model creates a single leaf. . .

Comment: It's a warning from `tibble` letting you know that they don't want to set rownames on tibbles and intend to convert the warning into an error in the future. Unfortunately `caret` uses rownames still. Just use `as.data.frame` to avoid the warning. Most likely it has nothing to do with your model not working.

Answer (score 1):

I moved from `data.frame` to `data.table` - no warnings anymore, and I can manipulate the data much faster and easier with my SQL background.